# Psplot position on page

Tags: positioning, pstricks, pst-plot

How can i move \psplot on custom position without pstpicture?

```
\psset{yunit=28pt,xunit=28pt}
    \psplot[algebraic=true,linewidth=1pt,plotpoints=500]{0}{4.7}{(-x/5)*cos(4*x)}
    \psplot[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=1pt]{0}{4.7}{x 5 div}
    \psplot[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed]{0}{4.7}{x -5 div}
```

Comment: Please prove MWE (minimum working example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}    
\begin{document}

\psdot(0,0)% Toi see where we are
\rput(3,-3){%
    \psplot[algebraic=true,linewidth=1pt,plotpoints=500]{0}{4.7}{(-x/5)*cos(4*x)}%
    \psplot[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=1pt]{0}{4.7}{x 5 div}%
    \psplot[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed]{0}{4.7}{x -5 div}%
}

\end{document}
```